# Does Appcelerator support JQuery and CSS3 100%

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, native, appcelerator

I previously created a magazine app using PhoneGap and I wasn't satisfied with the performance of the app. I did my homework and researches brought me to appcelerator. I can't seem to find in Appcelerator whether there is a 100% support with Jquery (with all its plugins) and CSS3 transforms. I want to know if I am not wasting my time learning the API because my magazines NEED CSS3 and the use of some JQuery plugins. Please mention as well if there is a better way to satisfy my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium Desktop uses the webkit engine, So you'll get whatever html5/css3 features webkit has.

Titanium mobile moved to a JavaScript-based workflow, but you can still pull up a WebView which would allow you to use html + css for development. (again, webkit based)

see: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.UI.WebView

Native-based views will be faster than using WebViews.

Comment: How about the performance? Do I have to expect it to be the same with PhoneGap? Or can I mix the javascript-based page and when I need the features of css3 / jquery, i'll make use of the webview?

Comment: Titanium will more easily give you a native feel and a performance boost. The WebView will slow it down but PhoneGap runs in a WebView by default so PhoneGap is guaranteed to be slower. Think of Titanium as a framework for writing native apps using js and PhoneGap as your mobile site running inside a browser that can't open tabs. They both interface with the native controls, but Titanium is running as a native app(slightly inaccurate) and PhoneGap is running as a WebView